# CycleGAN - artifacts and style not transferring

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I am using tf and Keras to create a cycleGAN following the approach used [here](https://hardikbansal.github.io/CycleGANBlog/) and [here](https://github.com/Shaofanl/CycleGAN-keras/blob/master/CycleGAN/models/cyclegan.py)

I am having some odd behaviors on the images generated by generators A->B and B->A

---

The following image shows, from left to right

- real_A (original image)
- generated_B ( generator_AtoB applied to real_A)
- generated_A ( generator_BtoA applied to the previous image)

and its counterpart

- real_B (original image)
- generated_A ( generator_BtoA applied to real_B)
- generated_B ( generator_AtoB applied to the previous image)

[image: GAN example]

Images 2 and 5 are the applications of the generators to the original images and they have very strong checkered artifacts (due to the deconvolution I guess) and show no signs of "morphing" from a horse to a zebra, and viceversa.

What I do not understand is that images 3 and 6 are exactly the same generators, applied to the "artifacted" image, but they do not show any sign of artifacts.

- am I doing something horribly wrong in training the generators?

Even after 10k epochs there are no signs of visual improvements:
- why images 2 and 5 shows no signs of style transfer?
- why images 2 and 5 shows very strong artifacts, but not 3 and 6 ?

---

**Full code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# https://hardikbansal.github.io/CycleGANBlog/
import sys
import time
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input, Dropout
from keras.layers import multiply, add as kadd
from keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU, ReLU
from keras.layers import Activation

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from PIL import Image


from custom_layers import ReflectionPadding2D


# NET PARAMETERS
ngf = 32 # Number of filters in first layer of generator
ndf = 64 # Number of filters in first layer of discriminator
BATCH_SIZE = 1 # batch_size
pool_size = 50 # pool_size
IMG_WIDTH = 256 # Imput image will of width 256
IMG_HEIGHT = 256 # Input image will be of height 256
IMG_DEPTH = 3 # RGB format
INPUT_SHAPE = (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH)

USE_IDENTITY_LOSS = False


# TRAINING PARAMETERS
ITERATIONS = 1000000
DISCRIMINATOR_ITERATIONS = 1
SAVE_IMAGES_INTERVAL = 100

SAVE_MODEL_INTERVAL = 1000

FAKE_POOL_SIZE=50

# DATASET="vangogh2photo"
DATASET="horse2zebra"



def resnet_block(num_features):

    block = Sequential()
    block.add(Conv2D(num_features, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="SAME"))
    block.add(BatchNormalization())
    block.add(ReLU())
    block.add(Conv2D(num_features, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="SAME"))
    block.add(BatchNormalization())
    block.add(ReLU())


    # resblock_input = Input(shape=(64, 64, 256))
    resblock_input = Input(shape=(128, 128, 256))
    conv_model = block(resblock_input)

    _sum = kadd([resblock_input, conv_model])

    composed =  Model(inputs=[resblock_input], outputs=_sum)
    return composed


def discriminator( f=4, name=None):



    d = Sequential()
    d.add(Conv2D(ndf, kernel_size=f, strides=2, padding="SAME", name="discr_"+name+"_conv2d_1"))
    d.add(BatchNormalization())
    d.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    d.add(Dropout(0.1))
    d.add(Conv2D(ndf * 2, kernel_size=f, strides=2, padding="SAME", name="discr_"+name+"_conv2d_2"))
    d.add(BatchNormalization())
    d.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    d.add(Dropout(0.1))
    d.add(Conv2D(ndf * 4, kernel_size=f, strides=2, padding="SAME", name="discr_"+name+"_conv2d_3"))
    d.add(BatchNormalization())
    d.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    d.add(Dropout(0.1))
    d.add(Conv2D(ndf * 8, kernel_size=f, strides=2, padding="SAME", name="discr_"+name+"_conv2d_4"))
    d.add(BatchNormalization())
    d.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    d.add(Dropout(0.1))
    d.add(Conv2D(1, kernel_size=f, strides=1, padding="SAME", name="discr_"+name+"_conv2d_out"))

    # d.add(Activation("sigmoid"))


    model_input = Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE)

    decision  = d(model_input)

    composed = Model(model_input, decision)
    # print(d.output_shape)
    # d.summary()

    return composed

def generator(name=None):

    g = Sequential()
    # ENCODER

    g.add(Conv2D(ngf, kernel_size=7,
            strides=1,
            # activation='relu',
            padding='SAME',
            kernel_initializer='random_normal',
            bias_initializer='zeros',
            input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE,
            name="encoder_"+name+"_0" ))
    # g.add(BatchNormalization())
    # g.add(ReLU())

    # g.add(ReflectionPadding2D())

    g.add(Conv2D(64*2, kernel_size=3,
            strides=2,
            padding='SAME',
            kernel_initializer='random_normal',
            bias_initializer='zeros',
            name="encoder_"+name+"_1" ))
    # g.add(BatchNormalization())
    # g.add(ReLU())
    # output shape = (128, 128, 128)

    # g.add(ReflectionPadding2D())

    g.add(Conv2D(64*4, kernel_size=3,
            strides=2,
            padding="SAME",
            kernel_initializer='random_normal',
            bias_initializer='zeros',
            name="encoder_"+name+"_2",
            ))
    # # g.add(BatchNormalization())
    # # g.add(ReLU())
    # # output shape = (64, 64, 256)

    # # END ENCODER



    # # TRANSFORM

    g.add(resnet_block(64*4))
    g.add(resnet_block(64*4))
    g.add(resnet_block(64*4))
    g.add(resnet_block(64*4))
    g.add(resnet_block(64*4))
    g.add(resnet_block(64*4))



    # # END TRANSFORM
    # # generator.shape = (64, 64, 256)

    # # DECODER

    g.add(Conv2DTranspose(ngf*2,kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="SAME"))
    # g.add(BatchNormalization())
    # g.add(ReLU())

    g.add(Conv2DTranspose(ngf*2,kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="SAME"))
    # # g.add(BatchNormalization())
    # # g.add(ReLU())

    g.add(Conv2D(3,kernel_size=7, strides=1, padding="SAME", name="generator_out_layer"))
    g.add(ReLU())
    g.summary()
    # exit()


    # END DECODER

    model_input = Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE)
    generated_image = g(model_input)

    composed = Model(model_input, generated_image, name=name)
    return composed


def fromMinusOneToOne(x):
    return x/127.5 -1

def toRGB(x):
    return (1+x) * 127.5


def createImageGenerator( subset="train", data_type="A", batch_size=1, pp=None):

    # we create two instances with the same arguments
    data_gen_args = dict(
                         # rescale = 1./127.5,
                         # rotation_range=5.,
                         preprocessing_function= pp,
                         # width_shift_range=0.1,
                         # height_shift_range=0.1,
                         # zoom_range=0.1
                         )

    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

    # Provide the same seed and keyword arguments to the fit and flow methods
    seed = 1

    image_directory=subset+data_type
    print('data/'+DATASET+'/'+image_directory)
    image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/'+DATASET+'/'+image_directory,
        class_mode=None,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        seed=seed)

    return image_generator

def fit(
    generator_trainer,
    disc_trainer,
    generator_AtoB,
    generator_BtoA
    ):

    fake_A_pool = []
    fake_B_pool = []


    ones = np.ones((BATCH_SIZE,)+ generator_trainer.output_shape[0][1:])
    zeros = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE,)+ generator_trainer.output_shape[0][1:])

    zeros = np.sum([zeros, 0.07])

    train_A_image_generator = createImageGenerator("train", "A")
    # print(train_A_image_generator.next())
    # for c in train_A_image_generator:
    #     print(c)
    #     exit()
    # exit()

    train_B_image_generator = createImageGenerator("train", "B")
    # test_A_image_generator = createImageGenerator("test", "A")
    # test_B_image_generator = createImageGenerator("test", "B")

    now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S")
    it = 1
    while it  <= ITERATIONS:
        fw = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir="./tensorboard/"+now)
        start = time.time()
        print("\nIteration %d " % it)
        sys.stdout.flush()

        # THIS ONLY WORKS IF BATCH SIZE == 1
        real_A = train_A_image_generator.next()
        real_B = train_B_image_generator.next()

        fake_A_pool.extend(generator_BtoA.predict(real_B))
        fake_B_pool.extend(generator_AtoB.predict(real_A))

        #resize pool
        fake_A_pool = fake_A_pool[-FAKE_POOL_SIZE:]
        fake_B_pool = fake_B_pool[-FAKE_POOL_SIZE:]

        fake_A = [ fake_A_pool[ind] for ind in np.random.choice(len(fake_A_pool), size=(BATCH_SIZE,), replace=False) ]
        fake_B = [ fake_B_pool[ind] for ind in np.random.choice(len(fake_B_pool), size=(BATCH_SIZE,), replace=False) ]

        fake_A = np.array(fake_A)
        fake_B = np.array(fake_B)





        for x in range(0, DISCRIMINATOR_ITERATIONS):
            _, D_loss_real_A, D_loss_fake_A, D_loss_real_B, D_loss_fake_B = \
            disc_trainer.train_on_batch(
                [real_A, fake_A, real_B, fake_B],
                [zeros, ones * 0.9, zeros, ones * 0.9] )
                # [zeros, ones, zeros, ones] )


        print("=====")
        print("Discriminator loss:")
        print("Real A: %s, Fake A: %s || Real B: %s, Fake B: %s " % ( D_loss_real_A, D_loss_fake_A, D_loss_real_B, D_loss_fake_B))

        if USE_IDENTITY_LOSS:
            _, G_loss_fake_B, G_loss_fake_A, G_loss_rec_A, G_loss_rec_B, G_loss_id_A, G_loss_id_B = \
                generator_trainer.train_on_batch(
                    [real_A, real_B],
                    [zeros, zeros, real_A, real_B, real_A, real_B])
        else:
            _, G_loss_fake_B, G_loss_fake_A, G_loss_rec_A, G_loss_rec_B = \
                generator_trainer.train_on_batch(
                    [real_A, real_B],
                    [zeros, zeros, real_A, real_B])

                # generator_trainer outputs:
                # [discriminator_generated_B,   discriminator_generated_A,cyc_A,      cyc_B,]




        print("=====")
        print("Generator loss:")

        if USE_IDENTITY_LOSS:
            print("Fake B: %s, Cyclic A: %s || Fake A: %s, Cyclic B: %s || ID A: %s, ID B: %s" % (G_loss_fake_B, G_loss_rec_A, G_loss_fake_A, G_loss_rec_B, G_loss_id_A, G_loss_id_B))
        else:
            print("Fake B: %s, Cyclic A: %s || Fake A: %s, Cyclic B: %s " % (G_loss_fake_B, G_loss_rec_A, G_loss_fake_A, G_loss_rec_B))

        end = time.time()
        print("Iteration time: %s s" % (end-start))
        sys.stdout.flush()

        summary = tf.Summary(value=[
            tf.Summary.Value(tag="disc_A_loss_on_real", simple_value = D_loss_real_A),
            tf.Summary.Value(tag="disc_A_loss_on_generated", simple_value = D_loss_fake_A),
            tf.Summary.Value(tag="disc_B_loss_on_real", simple_value = D_loss_real_B),
            tf.Summary.Value(tag="disc_B_loss_on_generated", simple_value = D_loss_fake_B),

            tf.Summary.Value(tag="gen_generated_A", simple_value = G_loss_fake_A),
            tf.Summary.Value(tag="gen_generated_B", simple_value = G_loss_fake_B),
            tf.Summary.Value(tag="gen_cyc_A", simple_value = G_loss_rec_A),
            tf.Summary.Value(tag="gen_cyc_B", simple_value = G_loss_rec_B),
        ])

        fw.add_summary(summary, global_step=it)
        fw.flush()
        fw.close()

        if not (it % SAVE_IMAGES_INTERVAL ):
            imgA = real_A
            # print(imgA.shape)
            imga2b = generator_AtoB.predict(imgA)
            # print(imga2b.shape)
            imga2b2a = generator_BtoA.predict(imga2b)
            # print(imga2b2a.shape)
            imgB = real_B
            imgb2a = generator_BtoA.predict(imgB)
            imgb2a2b = generator_AtoB.predict(imgb2a)

            c = np.concatenate([imgA, imga2b, imga2b2a, imgB, imgb2a, imgb2a2b], axis=2).astype(np.uint8)
            # print(c.shape)
            x = Image.fromarray(c[0])
            x.save("data/generated/iteration_%s.jpg" % str(it).zfill(4))



        # with open("models/generator_AtoB.pickle", "wb") as saveFile:
        #     pickle.dump(generator_AtoB, saveFile)

        # with open("models/generator_BtoA.pickle", "wb") as saveFile:
        #     pickle.dump(generator_BtoA, saveFile)

        if not (it % SAVE_MODEL_INTERVAL):
            generator_AtoB.save("models/generator_AtoB_id.h5")
            generator_BtoA.save("models/generator_BtoA_id.h5")

        it+=1



    generator_AtoB.save("models/generator_AtoB_id.h5")
    generator_BtoA.save("models/generator_BtoA_id.h5")


    return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    generator_AtoB = generator(name="gen_A")
    generator_BtoA = generator(name="gen_B")

    discriminator_A = discriminator(name="disc_A")
    discriminator_B = discriminator(name="disc_B")





    ### GENERATOR TRAINING
    optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)

    input_A = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="input_A")
    generated_B = generator_AtoB(input_A)
    discriminator_generated_B = discriminator_B(generated_B)
    cyc_A = generator_BtoA(generated_B)


    input_B = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="input_B")
    generated_A = generator_BtoA(input_B)
    discriminator_generated_A = discriminator_A(generated_A )
    cyc_B = generator_AtoB(generated_A)


    # cyclic error is increased, because it's more important
    cyclic_weight_multipier = 10

    if USE_IDENTITY_LOSS:
        generator_trainer =  Model([input_A, input_B],
                         [discriminator_generated_B,   discriminator_generated_A,
                         cyc_A,      cyc_B,
                         generated_B,     generated_A ]
                         )
        losses =         [ "MSE", "MSE", "MAE",                   "MAE",                    "MAE", "MAE"]
        losses_weights = [ 1,     1,     cyclic_weight_multipier, cyclic_weight_multipier,  1,     1    ]
    else:
        generator_trainer =  Model([input_A, input_B],
                     [discriminator_generated_B,   discriminator_generated_A,
                     cyc_A,      cyc_B,])

        losses =         [ "MSE", "MSE", "MAE",                   "MAE"]
        losses_weights = [ 1,     1,     cyclic_weight_multipier, cyclic_weight_multipier]

    generator_trainer.compile(optimizer=optim, loss = losses, loss_weights=losses_weights)



    ### DISCRIMINATOR TRAINING

    disc_optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)

    real_A = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="in_real_A")
    real_B = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="in_real_B")

    generated_A = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="in_gen_A")
    generated_B = Input(batch_shape=(None, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_DEPTH), name="in_gen_B")

    discriminator_real_A = discriminator_A(real_A)
    discriminator_generated_A = discriminator_A(generated_A)
    discriminator_real_B =  discriminator_B(real_B)
    discriminator_generated_B = discriminator_B(generated_B)

    disc_trainer = Model([real_A, generated_A, real_B, generated_B],
                         [  discriminator_real_A,
                            discriminator_generated_A,
                            discriminator_real_B,
                            discriminator_generated_B] )


    disc_trainer.compile(optimizer=disc_optim, loss = 'MSE')


    #########
    ##
    ## TRAINING
    ##
    #########




    fit(generator_trainer,
        disc_trainer,
        generator_AtoB,
        generator_BtoA)
```

Comment: Have you already found the bug? I can't seem to see where you freeze the weights of the discriminator when you are training the generator and vice versa, was this the problem, if you already solved it? Or was it something different?

Comment: sadly i did not find the bug yet :( i already tried to freeze the weights of discriminator and viceversa, but in some implementations this is not done

Comment: ah, interesting! Because I'm working with CycleGANs as well and I haven't seen it yet, normally in training GANs the gradients are calculated, but the weights are not updated. From the pictures it looks like the cyclic loss is taking control. Could you maybe clarify the line  `_, D_loss_real_A, D_loss_fake_A, D_loss_real_B, D_loss_fake_B = disc_trainer.train_on_batch([real_A, fake_A, real_B, fake_B],[zeros, ones * 0.9, zeros, ones * 0.9])`? Shouldn't `real_A` correspond to ones, and `fake_A` to zeros? I'm very interested to find out what's causing your generators to perform like this...

Comment: hi, thank you for your interest, might i suggest we move the conversation to the chat room? i can share papers and relevant links i used as a reference that would be hard to share here as a comment ( https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189462/cyclegan-conversation )

Comment: btw, to answer your question , I read a reference that suggested to flip labels and use 1 as "generated label" and 0 for real images